# Bind child Properties to DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

Is there a way to bind the child properties of an object to datagridview? Here's my code:

```
public class Person
{
    private string id;
    private string name;
    private Address homeAddr;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public Address HomeAddr
    {
        get { return homeAddr; }
        set { homeAddr = value; }
    }
}

public class Address
{
    private string cityname;
    private string postcode;
    public string CityName
    {
        get { return cityname; }
        set { cityname = value; }
    }
    public string PostCode
    {
        get { return postcode; }
        set { postcode = value; }
    }
}
```

And I want to show ID, Name, CityName when an object of the type Person is binded to datagridview. Note that CityName is a property of HomeAddr.

Comment: Do you want CityName and PostCode in one column or in two separate columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, [I've found a way to do this, in FarPoint](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-use-customtypedescriptor-to-show.html).

But you *can* do this in DataGridView, if your object doesn't have a list type property.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have the DataGridView to AutoGenerateColumns = true, there's really no simple way to do this. Your best bet is to set up the DataGridView ahead of time, and manually populate the DataGridView.

Alternatively, you can implement the [ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) but that's a bit of a pain if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look here

http://www.mail-archive.com/advanced-dotnet@discuss.develop.com/msg06383.html

Answer (score 0):

BLToolkit has BLToolkit.ComponentModel.ObjectBinder

Those features are:

```
Support for field binding along with property binding.

Support for inner class field and property binding such as Order.Address.Line1.

Support for the ObjectView feature which is available by assigning an object view type to the ObjectBinder.ObjectViewType property. An object view is an object that implements the IObjectView interface. This interface includes only one property - object Object { get; set; }. An object view can implement additional properties based on the assosiated object. The ObjectBinder will combine all of these properties with main object properties and create a single PropertyDescriptor collection. This feature can be used to separate UI presentation logic from business model objects and to keep them clean. ObjectView should be a stateless, lightweight object as its single instance can be assigned to many assosiated objects.

The ObjectBinder is optimized for high performance applications such real-time multithreaded message processing and distribution banking systems. So it does not use reflection to access objects. The standard way (which is used by the BindingSource) is to call the TypeDescriptor.GetProperties method to get a PropertyDescriptor collection. This method creates property descriptors that access object properties by reflection. The ObjectBinder has its own mechanism to avoid unnessasy reflection and boxing/unboxing operations.
```